# .htaccess apache 2.4 - RewriteRule ^(pl)($|/) - [L]

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I moved from apache 2.2 to 2.4 but this code `RewriteRule ^(pl)($|/) - [L]` in .htaccess is not working now. I´v tried almost everything, but I am still not able to make it work.

Can somebody help? Please

Comment: First of all , make sure .htaccess(Accessfile) is enabled, by default its disabled. Check this link http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61009/how-to-enable-use-of-htaccess-in-apache-on-ubuntu

Comment: You should also explain what that line is meant to do... And what you mean by "is not working".

Comment: for example: I have this url mydomain.com/pl/some-article/ and now it uses .htaccess rules from root, I need it to use only .htaccess rules from dir mydomain.com/pl/. The part "some-article/" is only virtual...in "pl" dir is another WP installation

Comment: In which .htaccess do you have `RewriteRule ^(pl)($|/) - [L]` and what exactly is not working?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(pl)($|/) - [L]`  - is in root, but problem is that it still shows pages from root in PL dir

Comment: You should show full .htaccess from root directory and from `/pl/` directory

Answer (score 0):

htaccess in root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(pl)($|/) - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?myweb\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.myweb.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

htaccess in PL dir:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This should be added in question not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should be htaccess in `/pl/` dir:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pl/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works fine. I thought that problem could be only in root dir.